# JavaScript override DOM Document for use in Node.JS environment

Tags: javascript, dom, domdocument

I'm working on a library which uses Emscripten to compile C++ code into WebAssembly.

I want to get the same library to work in a headless / nodejs environment. Using JSDom I'm able to create a Document in a node.js like this

```
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
const jsdom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><body></body>`);
console.log("Dom is initialised? " + jsdom !== undefined);
console.log("Document " + jsdom.window.document);
```

and I can now reference `jsdom.window.document` throughout my JavaScript code.

However, WebAssembly/emscripten calls `document.xxx` directly.

Is there any way to override the JavaScript `document` variable so any code calling `document.xxx` gets the new variable?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer to this was really easy, for anyone who needs it.

You can override the global document and window variables with this code:

```
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><body></div></body>`);
(global as any).window = dom.window;
(global as any).document = dom.window.document;
console.log("Dom is initialised? " + window !== undefined);
console.log("Document " + document);
```